# What's the effective way to track SQL table change

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Bug tracking system wrote on asp.net,  and I need to track about bug updates and show history of a bug, what the current status, updates, etc...

So, i need to know which field was changed, and do something with the data.
I created another table, that has the tracking tables field's and the new value,
so on change I insert a updater key (on another table, indicate who change it and when), changed field name and the new value.

it's work awesome with c#, but I need a more sql's solution.

e.g the value field in my changes table, can be fk for X TABLE, Y TABLE or a simple number or string that i casting to string.

What you are think about my solution?
Can you offer a better one?

Comment: Stuff like this is highly vendor-specific - but *SQL* is just the query language, not a database product. So please tell us what ***concrete database*** (SQL Server? MySQL? Postgres? Interbase? DB2? Sybase? Oracle? Something else?) and which version of that database you're using.

Comment: You can respond to data changes using triggers, which are 100% vendor-specific.

Comment: And ***which version*** of SQL Server? There are quite a few, from 4.2 all the way through 2012 ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server offers Change Data Capture functionality (a good place to start with the documentation is [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933994%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)).

This functionality maintains change tables for tables (and other elements in the database, if you want).  Of course, such functionality implies overhead when modifying data.  But it seems to be what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for helping.
I want to know another data, who do the chagne (fk of employee table) and change time.
This can provide me that?

Comment: @podiluska . . . I thought so, but this features chart suggests that it is supported by other version (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=sql.105).ASPX).  I suspect I'm misreading something there.